# ng-model doesn't change value when field contains user input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I'm still fairly new to angular.js. This seems like it should be very simple, but I'm stumped.

I have an input field:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.txt">
```

And I have a button that calls this function in my controller on ng-click:

```
$scope.clearSearch = function() {
    $scope.search = {txt:"qqqqq"};
}
```

Clicking the button behaves as expected - the input value on the page becomes "qqqqq".  So the data binding seems correct.

However, if I type anything into the field first and then press the button, the input value does not change on the page - the input field keeps the value I typed.  Why is that?

What I'm really trying to do is clear the field, I'm just using "qqqqq" for illustration - setting the value to null has the same behavior.

Comment: this should work ? can u provide a http://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: Show us your full code. Are you inside an ng-repeat or any other directive that creates a child scope? Place `$scope.search = {};` right in the start of the controller and see what happens. [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/53rm586A1F7uDKMYw3cG)

Comment: This is inside an Ionic app, so it's a bit of work to extract the code, but your suggestion worked - I don't fully understand why.  If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It's probably that your input is being bound to a different scope with the $scope you are accessing. Have a look here to understand scope: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: @alex_c When you click clear it executes `$scope.search = {...}`, which means that `search` is create in scope now if it hasn't already. From the looks of it, it looked like it hadn't.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/kY8QZ3IIiVD8TIg6KqY1?p=preview looks good to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works:

Script:

```
angular.module('myapp',[])
            .controller('myctrl',function($scope){
                $scope.search = {text:'some input'};
                $scope.clearSearch = function () {
                    $scope.search={text:null};
                }
});
```

Markup:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="search.text"/>
      <button ng-click="clearSearch()">clear</button>
</div>
```

[In plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4qBLrK6ieTaw1xHhFd7o)